# How to pipe input to a src_block as stdin ?

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming, org-babel

Consider the following snippet of perl in org-babel, which uses `<STDIN>`.

```
** Ans 2
   #+begin_src perl :results output
     use Math::Trig;
     $rad = <STDIN>;
     $circumference = 2*pi*$rad;
     print "Circumference of circle is $circumference";
   #+end_src
```

Is it possible to pipe the input to this block from another block ?

Say :

```
#+begin_src text :name test-input
  12.5
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `$rad` directly to the perl script from a `#+results` block : see [passing arguments to code blocks](http://orgmode.org/org.html#var) in the manual.

That would give

```
#+begin_src perl :results output :var rad=test-input
```

Using as input

```
#+results: test-input
:  12.5
```

Comment: This seems like exactly the answer. I'm not sure why you say "I don't think so".

Comment: You are right, I adapted the answer. (Originally it was because we're using a `results` block, and not a `begin_src text` one - see his question before the edit.)

Comment: Ah, okay. Cool.